# UPS shipping request - XML form is well formed but document is invalid (10002)

Tags: xml, ups

here is the sample request, it gives me this error "Failure: The XML document is well formed but the document is not valid (10002)" please can anyone help ?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><ShipmentConfirmRequest><Request><TransactionReference/><RequestAction>ShipConfirm</RequestAction><RequestOption>validate</RequestOption></Request><Shipment><Description>Order ID 3</Description><Shipper><Name>Planet Security USA - CCTV Store</Name><AttentionName>Planet Security USA - CCTV Store</AttentionName><ShipperNumber></ShipperNumber><PhoneNumber>+1 (305) 455-1722</PhoneNumber><EMailAddress>info@planetsecurityusa.com</EMailAddress><Address><AddressLine1>1936 NW 82nd Ave</AddressLine1><City>Doral</City><StateProvinceCode>FL</StateProvinceCode><PostalCode>33166</PostalCode><CountryCode>US</CountryCode></Address></Shipper><ShipTo><CompanyName>mmd</CompanyName><AttentionName>mmd</AttentionName><EMailAddress>mmsagencyusa@gmail.com</EMailAddress><Address><AddressLine1>228 Park Ave S</AddressLine1><StateProvinceCode>NY</StateProvinceCode><PostalCode>10003</PostalCode><CountryCode>US</CountryCode></Address></ShipTo><ShipFrom><CompanyName>Planet Security USA - CCTV Store</CompanyName><AttentionName>Planet Security USA - CCTV Store</AttentionName><PhoneNumber>+1 (305) 455-1722</PhoneNumber><Address><AddressLine1>1936 NW 82nd Ave</AddressLine1><City>Doral</City><StateProvinceCode>FL</StateProvinceCode><PostalCode>33166</PostalCode><CountryCode>US</CountryCode></Address></ShipFrom><SoldTo><CompanyName>mmd</CompanyName><AttentionName>mmd</AttentionName><Address><AddressLine1>228 Park Ave S</AddressLine1><StateProvinceCode>NY</StateProvinceCode><PostalCode>10003</PostalCode><CountryCode>US</CountryCode></Address></SoldTo><PaymentInformation><Prepaid><BillShipper><AccountNumber>14X6A9</AccountNumber></BillShipper></Prepaid></PaymentInformation><Service><Code>11</Code><Description>UPS Standard</Description></Service><RateInformation><NegotiatedRatesIndicator/></RateInformation><Package><Description>636</Description><PackagingType><Code>02</Code><Description></Description></PackagingType><PackageWeight><Weight>4</Weight><UnitOfMeasurement><Code>LBS</Code><Description></Description></UnitOfMeasurement></PackageWeight><Dimensions><Length>6</Length><Height>12</Height><Width>6</Width><UnitOfMeasurement><Code>IN</Code><Description></Description></UnitOfMeasurement></Dimensions><PackageServiceOptions/></Package><ShipmentServiceOptions/><ReferenceNumber><Code>IK</Code><Value>3</Value></ReferenceNumber></Shipment></ShipmentConfirmRequest>
```

I am using gabrielbull/php-ups-api in laravel for shipping through UPS.

Comment: It is normal for an XML document to be well-formed, but not valid. Please share your UPS **XML schema** (XSD ?!) the document is failing the validation process.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following document covering what you need: [UPS OnLine® Tools  Shipping XML Tool  Developers Guide](https://www.theaiatrust.com/wp-content/uploads/pli-db/68/Ship_Tool_02_09_09.pdf)

It reveals the following:
(1) **ShipperNumber** element value is mandatory.
(2) **PhoneNumber** element value accepts just digits 0-9.
(3) Etc.

You need to check the entire XML document. Optional vs. mandatory XML elements, and length and formatting of the actual data values.

> indented XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ShipmentConfirmRequest>
    <Request>
        <TransactionReference/>
        <RequestAction>ShipConfirm</RequestAction>
        <RequestOption>validate</RequestOption>
    </Request>
    <Shipment>
        <Description>Order ID 3</Description>
        <Shipper>
            <Name>Planet Security USA - CCTV Store</Name>
            <AttentionName>Planet Security USA - CCTV Store</AttentionName>
            <ShipperNumber></ShipperNumber>
            <PhoneNumber>+1 (305) 455-1722</PhoneNumber>
            <EMailAddress>info@planetsecurityusa.com</EMailAddress>
            <Address>
                <AddressLine1>1936 NW 82nd Ave</AddressLine1>
                <City>Doral</City>
                <StateProvinceCode>FL</StateProvinceCode>
                <PostalCode>33166</PostalCode>
                <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
            </Address>
        </Shipper>
        <ShipTo>
            <CompanyName>mmd</CompanyName>
            <AttentionName>mmd</AttentionName>
            <EMailAddress>mmsagencyusa@gmail.com</EMailAddress>
            <Address>
                <AddressLine1>228 Park Ave S</AddressLine1>
                <StateProvinceCode>NY</StateProvinceCode>
                <PostalCode>10003</PostalCode>
                <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
            </Address>
        </ShipTo>
        <ShipFrom>
            <CompanyName>Planet Security USA - CCTV Store</CompanyName>
            <AttentionName>Planet Security USA - CCTV Store</AttentionName>
            <PhoneNumber>+1 (305) 455-1722</PhoneNumber>
            <Address>
                <AddressLine1>1936 NW 82nd Ave</AddressLine1>
                <City>Doral</City>
                <StateProvinceCode>FL</StateProvinceCode>
                <PostalCode>33166</PostalCode>
                <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
            </Address>
        </ShipFrom>
        <SoldTo>
            <CompanyName>mmd</CompanyName>
            <AttentionName>mmd</AttentionName>
            <Address>
                <AddressLine1>228 Park Ave S</AddressLine1>
                <StateProvinceCode>NY</StateProvinceCode>
                <PostalCode>10003</PostalCode>
                <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
            </Address>
        </SoldTo>
        <PaymentInformation>
            <Prepaid>
                <BillShipper>
                    <AccountNumber>14X6A9</AccountNumber>
                </BillShipper>
            </Prepaid>
        </PaymentInformation>
        <Service>
            <Code>11</Code>
            <Description>UPS Standard</Description>
        </Service>
        <RateInformation>
            <NegotiatedRatesIndicator/>
        </RateInformation>
        <Package>
            <Description>636</Description>
            <PackagingType>
                <Code>02</Code>
                <Description></Description>
            </PackagingType>
            <PackageWeight>
                <Weight>4</Weight>
                <UnitOfMeasurement>
                    <Code>LBS</Code>
                    <Description></Description>
                </UnitOfMeasurement>
            </PackageWeight>
            <Dimensions>
                <Length>6</Length>
                <Height>12</Height>
                <Width>6</Width>
                <UnitOfMeasurement>
                    <Code>IN</Code>
                    <Description></Description>
                </UnitOfMeasurement>
            </Dimensions>
            <PackageServiceOptions/>
        </Package>
        <ShipmentServiceOptions/>
        <ReferenceNumber>
            <Code>IK</Code>
            <Value>3</Value>
        </ReferenceNumber>
    </Shipment>
</ShipmentConfirmRequest>
```